# Is there any way to create master pages in a JSP web solution?

Tags: jsp, master-pages

We could simply create master pages in ASP.net, similarly is there any simple methology for JSP too? to reduce the amount of recording on your web pages?

Comment: Google for "JSP templating engine".

Comment: Thank You ! It reduces recording :)